# how to escape single quotes in grep

Tags: linux, grep

I found a few questions here similar to this but they are not quite identical.

I want to grep for the text `'true' format` in certain files.

How do I do it?

Not sure how to escape the single quotes around `true`.

Comment: Please note that you are not escaping the single quotes in grep.  You are escaping the single quotes in the shell.

Comment: @AndyLester OK, I see, noted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just wrap the string within double quotes:

```
grep "'true' format" your_file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
this is 'true' format
and this is true formatting
test

$ grep "'true' format" a
this is 'true' format
```

Comment: OK, thanks, seems to work fine (with or without -F). But what if in the string I am looking for I have both " and '. Then what do I surround my search text with? :) Just curious.

Comment: Well in that case there is no easy solution without escaping. Maybe you can store the pattern in another file (say `b` containing `this is 'tr"ue' format`) and then grep based on file: `grep -f b a`.

Comment: To quote the string `"'"` (double, single, double) in Bash (at least): `'"'"'"'"'`, i.e. single quotes around the whole thing and for single quotes a closing single quote, then a double quoted single quote and then a single quote again to "reset". (I hope that's readable.)

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the `-P` (Perl regex syntax) flag of `grep`, then you can encode `'` as `\x27` in the pattern:

```
grep -P '\x27true\x27 format' file.txt
```

(Similarly, for `"` use `\x22`)

Answer (score 0):

Use escapes:

```
grep -i "'true' format" file.txt
```

Comment: Note `-i` states for (from `man grep`):  Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.